# Error While enumerating group membership on local machine

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if a user is a member of a group like:

```
if (conditionalGroup != null)
            {
                if (!currentUser.IsMemberOf(conditionalGroup))
                {
                    _logger.Debug("Adding user to Specific group.");
                    conditionalGroup.Members.Add(currentUser);
                    conditionalGroup.Save();
                }

                conditionalGroup.Dispose();
            }
```

However it fails with this: `An error (1789) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved.`

This group is the Users group on the local machine. I also do the same thing with the IIS_IUSRS group and that one is fine. This just started today on my build machine and has always worked before. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here is how I create the User:

pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
                currentUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, u.UserName);

```
            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                currentUser = new UserPrincipal(pc)
                    {
                        Name = u.UserName,
                        Description = u.UserDescription,
                        UserCannotChangePassword = false,
                        PasswordNeverExpires = true
                    };

                currentUser.SetPassword(u.UserPassword);
                currentUser.Save();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you usually see all users and groups with their names. But. sometimes occassionally you find a user or group that is displayed not by name, but by it's SID. This happens when the System find an entry that claims to refer to such ID, but the ID is not registered or not found in the System's name table/database.

The easiest way to see that is to borrow someone's pendrive with NTFS partition on it and some user-files created on remote machine that has different accounts. Browse, rightclick, see Permissions, voila lots of SIDs.

Start with inspecting your group that 'fails', ie. in SystemTools there's an applet ComputerManagement where you can browse most of the User and Groups registrations. View that Group, see its members and check if all of them are seen by-name, and none by "S-1-5..." number. If you find numeric one, try checking the classification support.microsoft.com/kb/243330 - maybe you will guess how that user got added there and why he is unnamed.

Anyways, which line of that code fails actually? IsMemberOf or Members.Add or Save?

Comment: The IsMemberOf fails it never makes it to the other lines. Also I have deleted all the users that I have created and when I create a new one above this I still get the same error.

Comment: I inspected the users group and this is what I have: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users (S-1-5-11) , NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE (S-1-5-4) , There is also a mydomain\Domain Users

Comment: Before you paste - I don't exactly know the workflow of creating new users by code.. When you add the user to the `conditionalGroup`, is the User already created and **present** on the system? Maybe you are trying to update a Group's MemberList before the new user is registered in the system at all? Or maybe the user-registration has only _started_ and system didn't finished propagating the new-user-information to some crucial parts? ActiveDirectory/DomainController/etc? Put a breakpoint on that line and when the program halts, check whether the user exists

Comment: hm.. auth-users and interactive are normal and always known to the system.. But the domainusers may pose a problem, are you in the domain? are you creating a local or domain user? - see above comment

Comment: Actually, I have no other ideas than that, sorry:/

Comment: I added the method I use to create the user above. Basically I first check if it exists on the local machine hence and if not then I create it and save it. Also the domain is the domain that I am a member of, but I am creating a local user not a domain user. I just don't understand why the other group works and this one doesn't.

Comment: I'm glad you've passed that, but that was very strange. Pity we do not know what was that. I hope you will not hit that again!